# Solving an exponential equation with logoarithm laws

Tags: exponential-function

$$2(5)^x = 3^{x+1}$$

I am trying to solve for $x$ in the above equation. Is there a way to make the bases the same to solve? Can I simplify the left side to $10^x$? I'm really not sure where to start to be honest. Here's what I've tried:

$$x\log 10 = (x+1)\log3$$

$$x = \frac{\log10}{\log3}$$

$$x = 0.477121$$

I'm not confident with the answer.. Is it correct? Any ideas?

Comment: is it $2\cdot5^x=3^{x+1}$

Comment: 5 is in parentheses, but yes.

Comment: $$\log [2 (5^x)] = \log(2) + x \log(5)$$ Then solve for $x$.

Comment: $2\cdot5^x\color{red}\ne10^x$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take the logaithm of both sides then you will get
$\ln(2)+x\ln(5)=(x+1)\ln(3)$ this must be solved for $x$
we have $\ln(2)+x\ln(5)=x\ln(3)+\ln(3)$ thus we get
$x(\ln(5)-\ln(3))=\ln(3)-\ln(2)$
therefore $x=\frac{\ln(3)-\ln(2)}{\ln(5)-\ln(3)}$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So how do I isolate x from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$2\cdot5^x=3^{x+1}\\2\cdot5^x=3\cdot3^x\\(\frac{5}{3})^x=\frac{3}{2}\\x\log(\frac{5}{3})=\log(\frac{3}{2})\\x(\log(5)-\log(3))=\log(3)-\log(2)\\x=\frac{\log(3)-\log(2)}{\log(5)-\log(3)}$$